# ForkJoin Issue on angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I make this code for test forkJoin but it does not work!
Can you check what is the problem?

```
const observables = [];

observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next('Hello')));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next(' ')));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next('World') ));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next('!')));

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(word => console.log(word.join('')));
```

Comment: The observables must complete. Just use `Observable.of('Hello')` to create an Observable that emits Hello and then completes.

Comment: Hum, in this case, if i use 
      `observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => { subscriber.next('Hello');subscriber.complete();}));`
Solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
const observables = [];

observables.push(Observable.of('Hello'));
observables.push(Observable.of(' '));
observables.push(Observable.of('World'));
observables.push(Observable.of('!'));

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(word => console.log(word.join('')));
```

Comment: Hello, this work but without Observable `observables.push(of('Hello'));`

Comment: @jrelo that's because you use lettable, aka pipeable operators/functions, instead of traditional operators.

Comment: what is better?

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md. I prefer the traditional ones (I find them more readable, and the IDE can autocomplete and infer types better), but pipeable operaors have other advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Is important complete the observable for forkJoin work, like the example!

```
const observables = [];

observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next('Hello');
  subscriber.complete();
}));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(' ');
  subscriber.complete();
}));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next('World');
  subscriber.complete();
}));
observables.push(new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next('!');
  subscriber.complete();
}));
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(word => console.log(word.join('')));
```